# How to show the user the posts (or movies) in this case they have liked?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-templates

I have a user profile page where I want to show the user the movies they have liked.
Here is the part of model which contains the like field as an ManyToManyField.

```
class moviefiles(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    .
    .  
    .
 liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='movie_like')
    rt = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Here is the def in view for liking or unliking:

```
def movieLike(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        post = get_object_or_404(moviefiles, slug=request.POST.get('post_id'))
        liked = False  
        if post.liked.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.liked.remove(request.user)
            liked = False 
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('movie-about', args=[str(slug)]))
        else:
            post.liked.add(request.user)
            liked = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('movie-about', args=[str(slug)]))
    else: 
        return redirect('/user/signup')
```

I am using MongoDB as the database and django made two tables in it on running `makemigrations`, one is the `home_moviefiles` and another is `home_moviefiles_liked` which is storing the liked data and the data of liking or unliking is getting saved correctly.
I'm trying to retrieve the the movies which a user has liked but I am unable to proceed from here.

Comment: `moviefiles.objects.filter(liked=request.user)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem tried that already. Returns an empty QuerySet.